# Enabling 'reuse last entered value' when creating adding field with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-form

When I create a vector and add fields:

```py
fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField("True_Class", QVariant.Int))
```

How can I set the `"True_Class"` field to *'reuse entered value'* as if I was using the dialog box settings below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To modify this value try the [`setReuseLastValue()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsEditFormConfig.html#ad4f2cd2a30bf24c425afbf7fdaeed5d2) method from the `QgsEditFormConfig` class.

Try the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def reuse_entered_value(layer_name: str, column_name: str, reuse: bool) -> None:
    """
    Activates the reuse last entered value for a single column in the Attributes table of a layer
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param column_name: name of the target column
    :param reuse: if the reuse last entered value shall be active
    """
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    column_index = layer.fields().indexOf(column_name)

    layer_form_config = layer.editFormConfig()
    layer_form_config.setReuseLastValue(column_index, reuse)
    
    layer.setEditFormConfig(layer_form_config)
    
    return

reuse_entered_value('points', "String", True)
```

*Before:*
[image: input]

*After:*
[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [GIS Unchained | Configure editing form widgets using PyQGIS](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/09/30/configure-editing-form-widgets-using-pyqgis/)

Comment: works great! thx!